# iOS discussion board / comments board API or sample?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to find examples of code libraries or sample code for adding a commenting functionality in my apps. I've successfully implemented the Disquser iOS wrapper (http://bit.ly/iadisquser) in a couple of my apps but find it difficult to manage. I've seen other apps that incorporate a commenting feature that's cool, including theCHIVE Lite app, that looks like its using Facebook maybe?? Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Gee that was tremendously helpful...!

Comment: I'd Love to help you, as would many other users of SO that spend a lot of time on here answering people's questions. If you come and ask a question that shows you've done a little research and then you've got stuck on something specific, then great. But if you ask a really general question that could be answered by Google, it's a little difficult to help you. Are you looking for something like this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html

Comment: Thanks that was actually helpful. I don't post unless I've already done a search on google. I was looking for options or solutions to what I may have come across.

Comment: No worries, wasn't trying to be a pain in the ass :). I've added the link I put above as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [QuickBlox Custom Objects code sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios). I think it's what you need.

It represents user's notes, which he can create & comment. So, you can implement this comments logic into your apps and comment any item you want

Answer (score 0):

There's a good tutorial for building a chat app that may help you get started, you can find it here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html

Comment: Thanks, this helps a bit although it's a little heavier than I was hoping for.